# Why escape the first character of eval in .profile script?

Tags: bash, shell, anaconda

I've installed anaconda on a mac and I noticed that it appends the following to my .profile:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I am a bit perplexed by the escaping of the "\eval" and "\export" lines. What is the purpose of this? I suspect it has something to do with portability, but I have never seen this before.

Can someone explain what purpose it serves?

Comment: @Spencer: You are correct, my question is indeed a duplicate. Unfortunately it is not always apparent what to search for when you have a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quoted just in case it's aliased to other commands. See following example:

```
[STEP 101] $ alias foo='echo hello world'
[STEP 102] $ foo
hello world
[STEP 103] $ \foo
bash: foo: command not found
[STEP 104] $
```

According to bash manaul:

> The first word of each simple command, **if unquoted**, is checked to see if it has an alias.  If so, that word is replaced  by  the  text  of  the alias.